# Comparing 2 pairs of integers

Tags: java, math, integer, comparison

I have two integers, let's call them `x` and `y`. I want to compare these to my other two integers, `a` and `b`. I want to check if **either** `x` or `y` is equal to `a` and if the other one is equal to `b`, but I can't think of a short way to do it.

Here's the code I've got so far - is there a shorter way?

`if ((firstClickItem.getId() == 590 && secondClickItem.getId() == 1511)
        || (secondClickItem.getId() == 590 && firstClickItem.getId() == 1511)) {`

Comment: what about firstClickItem.getId() + secondClickItem.getId() == 2101 ? there are some assumptions behind this ... and it's ugly

Comment: @M.Page appears to have it, with some ugly assumptions.

Comment: The bigger question is why do you want to do this? For code style or optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is fine. 
 Few other way of doing it would be

```
if((x+y)==(a+b) && Math.abs(x-y)==Math.abs(a-b)){ 

if(Math.min(x,y)==Math.min(a,b) && Math.max(x,y)==Math.max(a,b)){
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use xor operator

```
boolean xTest;

if( (xTest=x==a)^(y==a) ? xTest ? y==b : x==b : false )
```

This will:

1. test x==a en store the result in `xTest`
2. perform a `x==a` xor `y==a`. if `false`, return `false`. If `true`, do 3
3. if `x==a` is `true`, test `y==b`. if `x==a` is `false`, test for `x==b`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a precise way of doing it, if you really want it to be short:

```
// check if either x or y is equal to a and if the other one is equal to b
int op = (x == a ? (y == b ? 1 : 0) : ((y == a) ? (x == b ? 1 : 0) : 0));
```

You can put the above condition in if statement too. Personally, I think this expression is not really readable, so you might want to consider that part too.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean valid1 = firstClickItem.getId() == 590 && secondClickItem.getId() == 1511;
boolean valid2 = secondClickItem.getId() == 590 && firstClickItem.getId() == 1511;

if (valid1 || valid2){
```

Comment: This didn't shorten anything. This is actually longer than the OP's implementation and does not allow the conditional to short-circuit without calculating the right-hand side first.

Comment: The or won't short circuit. But if short circuit is a concern the code would work as is.  The suggestion was more to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I suppose you could use set comparison:

```
public class MyTest {
   private final static Set<Integer> VALUES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(590, 1511));

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       if(VALUES.equals(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(getVal1(), getVal2())))) {
           System.out.println("Equal");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Not Equal");
       }
    }

    // Either way round will work.
    public static int getVal1() { return 590; }
    public static int getVal2() { return 1511; }
}
```